# How to merge multiple .csv files using the 1st column of one of them as a index (shell scripting)

Tags: shell, csv, awk

How to merge multiple .csv files using the 1st column of one of them as an index (pref shell scripting - awk)

88 .csv files that look like this 
input files names ZBND19X.csv

```
==> ZBND19X.csv <==
Gene,ZBND19X(26027342 pairs)
ENSTGUG00000013338 (GAPDH),984.31862471
ENSTGUG00000000915,862.597795025
ENSTGUG00000006651 (ARPP19),845.045872644
ENSTGUG00000005054 (CAMKV),823.404021741
ENSTGUG00000005949 (FTH1),585.628487964
```

and ZBND22V.csv

```
==> ZBND39X.csv <==
Gene,ZBND39X(26558640 pairs)
ENSTGUG00000013338 (GAPDH),971.678203888
ENSTGUG00000005054 (CAMKV),687.81249397
ENSTGUG00000006651 (ARPP19),634.296191033
ENSTGUG00000002582 (ITM2A),613.756010638
ENSTGUG00000000915,588.002298061
```

output file name RPKM_all.csv

```
Gene,ZBND19X(26027342 pairs),ZBND39X(26558640 pairs)
ENSTGUG00000013338 (GAPDH),984.31862471,971.678203888
ENSTGUG00000000915,862.597795025,588.002298061
ENSTGUG00000006651 (ARPP19),845.045872644,634.296191033
ENSTGUG00000005054 (CAMKV),823.404021741,687.81249397
ENSTGUG00000005949 (FTH1),585.628487964,0
ENSTGUG00000002582 (ITM2A),613.756010638,0
```

Adding the 0 when there is no corresponding value found.

Comment: how big are those files?  are you pairwise joining them resulting in 44 files, or all of them resulting in one 1 file?

Comment: hey! I want to merge all 88 files into 1 file. So the output would be:Gene,ZBND19X(26027342 pairs),ZBND39X(26558640 pairs), ... 88 Thanks.

Comment: how about typical size?

Comment: Files are around 289K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` can only work on two files at a time, here comes

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==1 {c++; h=h sep $2; sep=FS; next} 
                  {ks[$1]; a[$1,c]=$2} 
           END    {print h; 
                   for(k in ks) 
                     {printf "%s", k;
                      for(i=1;i<=c;i++) printf "%s", FS a[k,i]+0; 
                      print ""}}' files
```

disclaimier: only if the data can fit in memory, also the order will be lost but if important there are ways to handle it.

**Explanation** Conceptually creating a table (aka 2D array, matrix) and filling up the entries.  THe rows are indexed by key and columns by file number.  Since `awk` array is hashing the keys we treat header separately to stay in place.  `a[k,i]+0` is to convert missing elements to `0`.

Comment: Heya! That worked! Would you mind walking me trough it. I find awk real cryptic, but have been increasingly interested in doing stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is 'join'.

You can use the join command to match on the first column ( by default ) as long as the files are sorted.

Don't forget to sort your files.

Did I mention you need to sort your files ;)?   It's an easy mistake to make ( I've made that mistake plenty; hence the emphasis ).

```
sort  ZBND19X.csv >  ZBND19X.csv.sorted
sort ZBND39X.csv  > ZBND39X.csv.sorted
join -t, ZBND19X.csv.sorted ZBND39X.csv.sorted > RPKM_all.csv
```

Here's the contents of RPKM_all.csv after running above :

```
ENSTGUG00000000915,862.597795025,588.002298061
ENSTGUG00000005054 (CAMKV),823.404021741,687.81249397
ENSTGUG00000006651 (ARPP19),845.045872644,634.296191033
ENSTGUG00000013338 (GAPDH),984.31862471,971.678203888
Gene,ZBND19X(26027342 pairs),ZBND39X(26558640 pairs)
```

We can also look for rows that don't match like this:

```
$ join -v1 -t, ZBND19X.csv.sorted ZBND39X.csv.sorted | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,0}'
ENSTGUG00000005949 (FTH1),585.628487964,0

$ join -v2 -t, ZBND19X.csv.sorted ZBND39X.csv.sorted | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1,0,$2}'
ENSTGUG00000002582 (ITM2A),0,613.756010638
```

Now you can combine the whole thing:

```
sort  ZBND19X.csv >  ZBND19X.csv.sorted
sort ZBND39X.csv  > ZBND39X.csv.sorted
join -t, ZBND19X.csv.sorted ZBND39X.csv.sorted > RPKM_all.csv
join -v1 -t, ZBND19X.csv.sorted ZBND39X.csv.sorted | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,0}' >> RPKM_all.csv
join -v2 -t, ZBND19X.csv.sorted ZBND39X.csv.sorted | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1,0,$2}'  >> RPKM_all.csv
```

Comment: cool! How could I do this for the files within a directory though?